Linux Server swap memory problem
I have the same problem on all servers running Java processes.
I have lots of available memory. But my swap is full of Java-related pages.
But the system never cleans its swap, Java pages stay there "forever".
To clean it, I need to restart the services and run swapoff and swapon.
Can I resolve this with some configuration in the OS or in Java?

Have you consider changing swappiness?

You can tell java to use less memory from the command line that starts the service.

Disable swap completely. Looks like you could do fine without it. 99% of servers/PCs don't need it like ever.

IIRC, swap space is only released (when required) with a LRU (least recently used) algorithm, which is very fast. If your Java shared start-up code stays there, it does no harm, and may still optimize later Java processes.
